# Can questions be duplicate if the duplicate is on non Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

There are many sites that emulate the Stack Exchange look and feel, but aren't actually part of the network.

One such site is [ask.puppetlabs.com](http://ask.puppetlabs.com)

To qualify as a duplicate, do both questions need to reside in the *official* Stack Exchange network?

For example, look at these questions.

https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/4512/managing-packages/

https://superuser.com/questions/693219/puppet-packagemanagement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not just on the same network. We only mark questions as duplicates if they are on the same *site*, e.g. a question can exist on both SU and SO wihtout being marked as duplicates. See: [What to do with cross-site duplicates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates)

You can comment with a link to that other site, if you want to. If you wish to provide an answer, please make sure the answer is more than purely a link - and don't just copy entire answers from other sites, if possible. If you do, make sure to credit the source in accordance to their content licence (SE uses CC-BY-SA).

Generally, even if an answer can be found by searching we would prefer to also add the answer on SE, in line with our goals of being a single source of knowledge.

Comment: I'd like to add that the *same user asking the same question on multiple SE sites* (cross-posting) is generally not OK. If you asked on the wrong site (wrong audience, no answers for weeks, ...) flag your question and request migration.